# Setting UIButton text edgeInsets but now text will not respond to touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need an image and text in my UIButton, but when moving the title edgeinsets the text is NOT clickable?

```
 [self.tweetButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"shareTweet.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.tweetButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(7.0, 5.0, 5.0, -55.0)];
[self.tweetButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamRounded-Light" size:18]];
[self.tweetButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(twitter:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: NSLog the frame and bounds of both the tweetButton and the tweetButton.titleLabel and see what you get.  Maybe the title is being drawn outside of the button.

Comment: I am sure it is because the button is 45 wide and the image and text together are 120 in width.

Comment: AFAIK the only part that will be clickable is the part contained in self.tweetButton.frame

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Made the button longer 150px.  Then did this.

```
 [self.tweetButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"shareTweet.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.tweetButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(7.0, 5.0, 5.0, -25.0)];
[self.tweetButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamRounded-Light" size:18]];
[self.tweetButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(twitter:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.tweetButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```